# Ajax Form: Submitting form a second time results in no success message being displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I have written an AJAX form script. After submit, the form gets validated in PHP. If everything is alright, a success message is displayed. If there were validation errors, I point the user to the corresponding fields so that the input can be easily corrected.
After that, the form has to be submitted again of course.

The initial function is called using `$("form").submit`. To allow a re-submit after validation errors have been corrected, I do

```
$(".error-msg").click( function () {
    $("form").submit();
});
```

(Yes, the form get submitted by clicking the error message.)

That works, I can see the data getting POSTed, but there is no success message displayed. Why? Is there a callback for `.submit` that can be used in a recursive way?

**Edit**

As per request -  more code:

```
$("form").submit(function () {

        var name     = $( "input[name=name]" ),
            mail     = $( "input[name=email]" ),
            message  = $( "textarea[name=message]" );

        var string = "name=" + name.val() + "&email=" + mail.val() + "&message="  + encodeURIComponent(message.val());

        $( "form input" ).attr( "disabled", "true" );
        $( "form textarea" ).attr( "readonly", "true" );

        $.ajax({
            url: "my-form.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: string,
            dataType: "json",
                success: function ( result ) {

                    if ( result.status === "success" ) {

                        alert( "success" );

                    }

                    if ( result.status === "fail" ) {

                            alert( "fail" );

                            $.each( result.data, function( k , v ) {

                                $( "#" + v.field ).removeAttr( "disabled" ).after("<p>" + v.errorMsg + "</p>");

                                $(".error").animate({
                                    opacity: 1
                                }, 500);

                                $(".error").click( function () {
                                    $("form").submit();
                                });

                            });

                    }
                }

        return false;
    })
```

Comment: can you post more of your code? and .submit doesnt not have a callback param. It has the handler and if needed eventData.

Comment: If you seen that data was posted to server and data was correct you should debug your php script. It is no matter how many times form was submitted!

Comment: syntax prblem ...missing a set of closing braces which puts `return false` in wrong place.

Comment: yes, add the missing `});` and return false in between the closing ajax and closing submit and if that doesnt work try to use .on click with your error submit. here it is in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/davidchase03/EYWQY/

Comment: Yes it works, cool thanks a bunch! I did not realize that there was a syntax error. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it :-)